# CSS transition height property not working

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to transition the height of my #superheader element smoothly, but something is going wrong.  My staging site is [here](https://staging-alumninations.kinsta.cloud/).  I'm able to get it working correctly with the snippet below, but it seems something is getting lost in translation. Any ideas?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // hiding superheader after scrolling a little ways
  $( window ).scroll(function() {
    var cutoff = 70;
    if ($(window).scrollTop()>200) {
      $("#superheader").addClass('hide');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop()<200) {
      $("#superheader").removeClass('hide');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#superheader {
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 700;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 20px 25px;
        width:100%;
        display:flex;
        transition: all .4s;
        height:80px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}

 #superheader.hide {
    height:20px;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#page {
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='superheader'></div>
<div id='page'></div>
```

Comment: There is another definition in your site's [theme](https://staging-alumninations.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/themes/buddyboss-theme/assets/css/theme.min.css?ver=1.6.3), which is impacting yours: `.hide { display: none!important; }` Using a different class might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @showdev comment, the problem because there is `hide` styling from your theme that add `display:none` , and it breaks the animation. all you can do is either:

1. change the class (for example from `.hide` to `.hidden`)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // hiding superheader after scrolling a little ways
  $( window ).scroll(function() {
    var cutoff = 70;
    if ($(window).scrollTop()>200) {
      $("#superheader").addClass('hidden');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop()<200) {
      $("#superheader").removeClass('hidden');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#superheader {
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 700;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 20px 25px;
        width:100%;
        display:flex;
        transition: all .4s;
        height:80px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}

 #superheader.hidden {
    height:20px;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#page {
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='superheader'></div>
<div id='page'></div>
```

2. or use the same class but just add `!important` on the display, like this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // hiding superheader after scrolling a little ways
  $( window ).scroll(function() {
    var cutoff = 70;
    if ($(window).scrollTop()>200) {
      $("#superheader").addClass('hide');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop()<200) {
      $("#superheader").removeClass('hide');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#superheader {
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 700;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 20px 25px;
        width:100%;
        display:flex !important; /* add this */
        transition: all .4s;
        height:80px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}

 #superheader.hide {
    height:20px;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#page {
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='superheader'></div>
<div id='page'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't see it.